# falha ao realizar update no CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3

Estou tentando editar um registro no CakePHP 3 e ao invés do sistema editar, ele está inserindo um novo registro.
EstatisticasController.php

```
public function editar($ID){
    $estatisticasTable = TableRegistry::get('Estatisticas');

    $estatistica = $estatisticasTable->get($ID);

    $this->set('estatistica', $estatistica);

    $this->render('nova');

}
```

Texto do index.ctp que está em \Template\Estatisticas\index.ctp

```
echo $this->Html->Link('Editar', ['controller' => 'estatisticas','action' => 'editar', $estatistica['ID']]);
```

Código para Salvar:

```
function salva(){ 

    $estatisticasTable = TableRegistry::get('Estatisticas'); 

    $estatistica = $estatisticasTable->newEntity($this->request->data()); 

    if($estatisticasTable->save($estatistica)){ 

        $msg = "Estatística Salva com Sucesso";

        $this->Flash->set($msg, ['element' => 'success']); 
    } 
    else { 
        $msg = "Erro ao tentar Salvar"; $this->Flash->set($msg, ['element' => 'error']); 
    } 
    $this->redirect('/Estatisticas/index'); 
}
```

Comment: E aonde fica o código do salvamento. Me parece que você não colocou ele aí.

Comment: @fabricio_wm edite sua pergunta e coloque o código lá, para ficar melhor visível

Comment: Tente utilizar [update](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#updating-data)